# PubSubPullSensor takes long time to respond to a message

Tags: google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-composer

I am creating a subscription in the cloud composer code with a dynamic subscription name. After that I have a PubSubPullSensor operator. Before this task starts I manually send a message to that topic with some attribute so that it can go that subscription. But after I publish a message in the topic, it takes a long time for the PubSubPullSensor, sometime more than 19 minutes.
Is it that attribute which is causing the issue of taking long time?
How can I resolve this?
Please let me know.

with DAG(
"pubsub_trigger_dy_sub_2",
schedule_interval=None,
catchup=False,
default_args=default_arguments,
) as dag:

```
def samplePythonFn():
    print("Getting called from cloud composer")
def _createSubscription(**kwargs):
    hook = PubSubHook()
    subscriptionName = "airflow-test-" + str(uuid.uuid4())
    application = "LumiPortal"
    result = hook.create_subscription(
        topic=topic,
        subscription=subscriptionName,
        expiration_policy={
            "ttl": Duration(seconds=24*60*60)
        },
        labels={
            "source": "dag"
        },
        filter_='attributes.correlid = "' + subscriptionName + '"'
        #f'attributes.correlid = "{subscriptionName}"'
    )
    ti = kwargs['ti']
    print(subscriptionName)
    print(application)
    ti.xcom_push(key='Subscription_1', value=subscriptionName)
    return subscriptionName

pull_messages_1 = PubSubPullSensor(
    task_id="pull_first_messages",
    ack_messages=True,
    max_messages=1,
    return_immediately=True,
    project_id=project_id,
    subscription="{{ task_instance.xcom_pull(task_ids='CreateSubscription_1') }}",
    dag=dag
)

start = DummyOperator(task_id='start')

create_subscription_task_1 = PythonOperator(
    task_id='CreateSubscription_1',
    python_callable=_createSubscription,
    provide_context=True,
)

call_stored_procedure_load = BigQueryInsertJobOperator(
    task_id="call_stored_procedure",
    configuration={
        "query": {
            "query": "CALL `amexpoc1.bqTableFullRefresh`('{}','{}','{}')".format(dataset, stage_table,main_table),
            "useLegacySql": False,
        }
    }
)


delete_subscription_task_1 = PubSubDeleteSubscriptionOperator(
    task_id='DeleteSubscription_1',
    subscription="{{ task_instance.xcom_pull(task_ids='CreateSubscription_1') }}"
)

def pullxcomm1(**kwargs):
    ti = kwargs['ti']
    fetched_first_message = ti.xcom_pull(key='return_value', task_ids=['pull_first_messages'])
    print(fetched_first_message)
    return fetched_first_message


pullxcomm_first_message = PythonOperator(
    task_id='pull_First_xcomm',
    python_callable=pullxcomm1,
    provide_context=True,
    dag=dag
)

end = DummyOperator(task_id='end')
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thanks, I added the code. PubSubPullSensor operator is taking huge time for me. Please help